# In Vim, how to find out what a key combination does

Tags: vim

I accidentally press a shorcut key, and I know that vim has done something but I don't know what.

How can I find out what that shortcut key does?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

There are two potential sources for information.  First of all, if it's a built in shortcut, it is normally in the help documentation.  For instance, if you do `:help CTRL-I`, it'll take you to a help entry about moving around your jump list.

It is possible, however, that you have a custom mapping from one of your `.vimrc` files or an underdocumented plugin.  In that case, try using `:map` which will list all custom keyboard mappings that are currently active.  That will give you three columns:

1. the mode the mapping applies to
2. the keyboard shortcut
3. the command that is run

You can then use `:help` to further investigate the command that is run.

Comment: I'm trying to work out what Shift-Enter is mapped to, but the output of `:map` doesn't try to represent Ctrl/Shift/etc bindings. So I have a lot of entries that are blank for what the key combination is. Any tips for that?

Comment: Greetings Hamish: The first source to check is the help files for a key mapping, such as `:help S-Enter` or `:help S-CTRL-J`.  However, I don't see the appropriate entry.  It does the same thing as `:help CTRL-F` in my install, however.

I'd suggest starting a new question to get more details for your particular query.

Comment: I actually worked out that `:map <key combo>` would tell me what the mapping was - see my answer below. But thanks for the other tips :)

Comment: what does : stand for??? it says I should press :wq to save and quit, but I have no idea what : stands for...

Comment: @dangalg: It literally means you should type the `:` key, the one normally to the left of the 'L' key.  Typing `:` puts you into command mode in Vim.

Comment: The colon ":" is usually to the *right* of the "L" key, I think, not the left.

Comment: Can I search in the results of `:map`? Say I want to know what key (if any) `bNext` is bound. Pressing `/` doesn't work.

Answer (score 37):

Just doing `:map` will show you lots of mappings, but if your mapping is <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> then the second column (which should show the keyboard shortcut) will be empty.

However you can ask map to tell you what a particular key combination is. Some examples that line up with the above examples:

```
:map <F2>
:map <S-CR>
:map <C-P>
```

Comment: In addition, note that `Ctrl-Q` will "quote" the next key event. Thus, suppose you do not know how to spell `Shift-Enter` in the vim notation (`<S-CR>` in the example), then you can press `:map` followed by `Ctrl-Q` followed by the key combination.

Answer (score 4):

You might check out the answers at [In Vim can I find out what keys I just typed?](https://superuser.com/questions/278170/in-vim-can-i-find-out-what-keys-i-just-typed) (If this is what you're looking for).