# How do I find out what a vim command does?

Tags: vim

Many vim blog posts will give a series of vim commands, but don't explain all of the details. How can a new user use vim's help to figure out how it works?

For example, here's a command from [this blog post](http://derekwyatt.org/2014/01/01/moving-from-wordpress-to-github-pages.html):

```
ggjV/---<cr>k:v/layout:\|title:/d<cr>
```

I recognize that `/layout:\|title:/` is a regex, but how can I find out what v/regex/d does?

Comment: Related: [In Vim, How to find out what a key combination does](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7047650/79125).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vim has three methods of looking up help:

- :help *keyword*

  - Look up *keyword* (supports partial matches and tab completion).
  - Good if you know what you're looking for.
- :helpgrep *query*

  - Grep all help for specific text *query*.
  - Good if you don't know what you're looking for.
- K

  - Look up help for the text under the cursor.
  - Only meaningful when editing vimscript.
  - tpope's [vim-scriptease](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease) has an improved `K` that figures out the type of command from the context (to differentiate `:call` from `call()`).

---

In this case, we know part of the command so we can use `:help`. But what keyword do we use?

Tab completion with the right prefixes makes it pretty quick to find what you're looking for if you already know something about the command:

- `:` is used for cmdline/Ex-mode commands

  - Example: `:help :help`
  - These are input at the bottom of the screen. See `:help :`
- `'` is used for options

  - Example: `:help 'incsearch'`
  - These are vim settings applied with `:set`. See `:help :set` and `:help option-list`.
- No prefix for normal mode commands

  - Example: `:help CTRL-]`
  - See `:help Normal-mode`
- `i_` for insert mode

  - Example: `:help i_CTRL-[`
  - See `:help Insert-mode`
- `v_` for visual mode

  - Example: `:help v_CTRL-]`
  - See `:help Visual-mode`

Vim command names almost always end at punctuation (non-word characters).

If we enter in the sequence of commands, we'll see that `v/layout` is typed in from the cmdline (input at bottom of screen). That means we need to include the colon. We'll ignore `/layout` since punctuation terminates the command name.

```
:help :v
```

Vim will give you the abbreviated name for the command and information about using it. In this case, it mentions that :v is "Same as :g!", so we can scroll up to look for :g! (:global).

In short, Vim help has everything you need: `:help help-summary` has the above information and more new user tips.

Comment: A nice complement to tab-completion is CTRL-D, which will show you all possible completions at once, for easy browsing.

Comment: @rampion: I use `set wildmenu wildmode=list,full` so showing all options is the default tab-completion behavior.