# What is "%:r" in vimrc file?

Tags: vim, filenames, vi

1. What is `%:r` in vimrc file?
2. what is difference between `:gcc` and `:!gcc` ?
3. what is `%` in vimrc file?

I'm studying vi/vim...but it's hard for me.
I want information about vimrc operations. where can I get it??

I really appreciate all answers.

Comment: suggestions: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474313/how-do-i-find-out-what-a-vim-command-does and https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2136/how-do-i-navigate-to-topics-in-vims-documentation/2137#2137 for using vim documentation.... you could also use the flag to move the question to https://vi.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's answer your questions in order…

1. **What is difference between `:gcc` and `:!gcc`?**

   `:something` is an *ex command*. You can find a complete list of available ex commands under `:help ex-cmd-index` and look for help on a specific command with `:help :something`.

   `:gcc` is not an existing ex command.

   `:!something` calls the external command `something` so `:!gcc` would call `gcc`.
2. **What is `%` in vimrc file?**

   It's not anything specific to your `vimrc`. When used as argument to an external command, it represents the current file name. Assuming the current file name is `foobar.c`, `:!gcc %` is expanded to `gcc foobar.c` before being passed to the shell.

   See `:help c_%`.
3. **What is `%:r` in vimrc file?**

   Again, it's not anything specific to your `vimrc`. `:r` is a file name modifier applied to the current file name. Assuming the current file name is `foobar.c`, `%:r` would be expanded to `foobar`.

   See `:help filename-modifiers`.

It looks like you are trying to make sense of a command similar to:

```
:!gcc % -o %:r
```

which, again assuming the current file name is `foobar.c`, should be expanded to:

```
gcc foobar.c -o foobar
```

before being sent to your shell… and result in a `foobar` executable right beside your `foobar.c`.

Comment: this is very much not in order

Comment: This is the *correct* order.

Comment: _Correct_ **how** exactly. I understand how it might makes sense to answer in a certain order but renumbering is unnecessary

Comment: It's correct because it deals with OP's questions in a logical, sequential way. The difference between `:<cmd>` and `:!<cmd>`is primordial, so I dealt with it first, introducing the notion of external command which is the context of what OP was trying to do. Then `%:r` is a special case of `%` so `%` must be explained before `%:r`, in the context set up in #1. Renumbering was necessary because it made the logical order clear, showing OP where their problem solving method fails and, hopefully, nudging them toward a more deliberate strategy. Which seemed much needed. Disagree if you want.

Answer (score 0):

1. Before explaining %:r we need to know what % refers to. The "%" sign in the vim command refers to the current file. For example what if you wanted to write a vim command to compile the current file which say is a cpp file, then you'd do something like g++ -o %:r.out. Here % refers to the current file that you're working with.
2. :gcc means that you're trying to run the command inside the vim editor and :!gcc means that whatever you're typing after the exclamation will be run in your terminal.
3. Explained the % so now what is :r? Well, :r is used to read the contents of another file %:r. Where %:r.out refers to a file that is renamed just by appending .out at the end of the name of the %(current) file.
   So if you do something like :!./%r.out then this runs/executes the compiled file which you had already created.